# CSS solution to stretch div vertically

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have 3 child div inside one parent div.
first and third div are of fixed height.
How do I get second div to occupy all the remaining space. Looking for only CSS solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="first">1</div>
    <div id="second">2</div>
    <div id="third">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{border:1px solid #000}
#parent{width:200px;height:300px}
#first{width:100%;height:50px;background-color:red}
#second{width:100%;height:auto;background-color:yellow}
#third{width:100%;height:50px;background-color:blue}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ncb57w/

Answer (score 3):

Try using *flex*.

```
#parent{width:200px;height:300px; display: flex; flex-direction:column}
#second{width:100%;height:auto;background-color:yellow; flex-grow: 100;}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n4ncb57w/4/

Watch out for IE compatibility http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Aside from some cross-browser issues, flex is the best solution for this *if* your project allows for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that:

1. we don't know the height of the parent `div`
2. the height of first and third divs (let's call them 'top' and 'bottom') are known in advance
3. the height of the second div (let's call it 'middle') is not known: it should take up all the space between the 'top' and 'bottom' divs (and only that space), regardless of how much or how little content it may have.

#### Solution 1: Use 'absolute' positioning with both 'top' and 'bottom'

If the 'middle' div uses absolute positioning, and you **don't** set its height, but do set both its 'top' and 'bottom', then it will automatically stretch to fill. I have not tested it, but the markup will look something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="top">
        Heading at the TOP!
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer...
    </div>

    <div id="bottom>
        ...and here is the BOTTOM.
    </div>
</div>
```

...and the stylesheet will look something like this:

```
#parent { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh; 
    position: relative; 
}

#top, #middle, #bottom { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

#top {
    top: 0px;
    height: 63px; // <- the set height of the top
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 96px; // <- the set height of the bottom
}

#middle { 
    // no 'height' - use both 'top' and 'bottom' instead
    top: 63px; // <- the set height of the top
    bottom: 96px // <- the set height of the bottom
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is probably the most straight-forward way, which is likely to have the best cross-browser support.

#### Solution 2: Use `calc()`

If you're not concerned about supporting older browsers - such as Internet Explorer 9 or earlier - then you can use `calc()` to get the browser to automatically calculate the height of the 'middle' div for you. The `calc()` built-in CSS function allows you to mix different units of measurement - like '%' and 'px' in your calculations. Using `calc()`, your stylesheet would look something like this:

```
#parent { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vh; // this is the parentHeight
    position: relative; 
}

#top, #middle, #bottom { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
}

#top {
    height: 63px; // <- the topHeight
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 96px; // <- the bottomHeight
}

#middle { 
    // Automatically calculate the height using 'calc'.
    // The formula for the calculated height should be:
    // (parentHeight - (topHeight + bottomHeight)):
    height: calc(100vh - 159px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

#### Solution 3: Use a Flexbox Layout

There are several tutorials online that cover how to achieve what you want - and much more - using the new 'flexbox' layout mode, so I won't cover it here. Flexbox is a relatively new addition to CSS, and although current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari support it extremely well, Internet Explorer 10 and 11 don't (it's quite buggy). Considering that there are easier, alternative solutions - like the ones above - at this point I'd probably go with one of these. Nevertheless, Flexbox is the future, and if you want to learn how to use it, this would be a good exercise: go and learn it! ;-)

There are probably other solutions which I haven't though of, so it'll be interesting to see how many suggestions are going to turn up here...

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use `calc`.

```
#second{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:yellow; 
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

And

```
#parent > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4ncb57w/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` method. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4ncb57w/2/)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px
}
#first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red
}
#second {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 106px);
  background-color: yellow
}
#third {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">1</div>
  <div id="second">2</div>
  <div id="third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the JSFiddle code in your post. Don't just turn a sentence into code via indentation. You need to put the code in your post for a reason...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the `calc()` function CSS provides.

```
second{height: calc(100% - 106px);}
```

So what is done here is we subtract the combined height of `#first` and `#third` from 100%. So in this case its 2x 52px(border included), now because `#second` also has a 1px border we subtract another 2 px.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pt00Lbh/3/)